# Can my algorithm description be improved?

Tags: algorithms

I'm writing a pseudocode description of the FISTA (with line search) algorithm from convex optimization.  (I'm using slide 17-18 [here](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/fgrad.pdf) as a source.)  Can anyone suggest any improvements to my latex code?  I'm interested in anything that improves the style or makes the presentation more clear, more standard, or more beautiful.  Here's a MWE, with output shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,algpseudocode,algorithm}
\newcommand{\prox}{\text{prox}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\caption{FISTA with line search}
\label{fistaAlg_lineSearch}
\begin{algorithmic}
\State Initialize $x^0 = v^0$ and $t^0 > 0$
\For{$k = 1,2,\ldots$}
\State $t = t^{k-1}/r$
\State $\text{accept} = \text{FALSE}$
\While{$\text{accept} \neq \text{TRUE}$}
\State $\theta = \begin{cases} 1 & \quad \text{if } k = 1 \\
\text{positive root of } t_{k-1} \theta^2 = t \theta_{k-1}^2(1 - \theta) & \quad \text{if } k > 1 \end{cases}$
\State $y = (1 - \theta) x^{k-1} + \theta v^{k-1}$
\State $x = \prox_{t g}(y - t \nabla f(y))$
\If{$f(x) > f(y) + \langle \nabla f(y),x - y \rangle + \frac{1}{2t} \| x - y \|_2^2$}
\State $t \gets r t$
\Else
\State $\text{accept} = \text{TRUE}$
\EndIf
\EndWhile
\State $t^k = t$
\State $x^k = x$
\State $v^k = x^{k-1} + \frac{1}{\theta}(x^k - x^{k-1})$
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Requests like these may solicit primarily opinion-based answers, and may be subject to closure. I think it's better to refine your post asking for specific, factual responses, rather than possibly-subjective requests.

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's true, but I don't know how to refine the question further.  I suspect that people looking at this will see clear ways to improve my code that I hadn't been aware of or thought of.

Comment: The first thing I see is the [lack of indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2472553/914686). While nothing will change in the output, it sure would make working with the code more comfortable.

Comment: Be careful because the superscript to t becomes a subscript in the definition of theta, and it's not at all clear what `\theta_{k-1}` is.

Comment: @egreg Ah, you're right, I'm not being consistent about superscripts and subscripts.  And yes, I agree it's not clear what $\theta_{k-1}$ is, good point.

Comment: This should be migrated to [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are not consistent with your assignment. In some lines you use `=` and others you use `\gets`.

Comment: @Werner Good point, how do you think I should fix that problem?  It seems weird to use \gets everywhere, but it also would seem weird to write $t = r t$.  I've been using an $=$ sign whenever the statement would remain valid as an assertion that the quantities on the left and right are equal.  What's the standard way of doing this?

Comment: Assertions seem commentary in nature, so I would reference them as such. Something like a pre- or post-condition. I would also create a macro `\assign` and let that to what you would use in an assignment, for consistency. Like `\newcommand{\assign}{\gets}` and then use `$y \assign x$`. That way you're consistent in your usage and notation.